# Can't add RelativeLayout to DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout

My MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

xml is :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
          android:background="#242a31"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0px" >


    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view.


          -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_LinearLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:below="@+id/left_LinearLayout"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_bg_key"
            android:background="@color/default_color"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But app crashes with error:

`android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to` `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`

I need to add edit field to left menu , or should I add it by adapter of

Comment: Looks like you need to add more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably trying something like:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

However your `ListView`'s parent is not a `DrawerLayout`. You should use the `RelativeLayout` as your drawer now:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_LinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/left_LinearLayout"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fetch the layout and list:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
mDrawer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
```

And open the drawer like this:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawer);
```